# Tikz rectangle in perspective

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a rectangle in perspective which looks like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1) -- (0,3) -- (2,5) -- (2,3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there an alternative way by declaring a rectangle

```
\tikzstyle{my_rectangle} = [rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm]
```

and rotate it around the upward pointing axis? And if yes how would I do the rotation?

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: While TikZ itself supports 3d coordinates, they are not in gerneral orthogonal or normal.  For that you should use tikz-3dplot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\tikzset{my_rectangle/.style={draw,rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[my_rectangle,canvas is zy plane at x=0] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]